# Error while installing Zabbix

Tags: 20.04, zabbix

I am trying to install Zabbix Server on Ubuntu 20.04.

I enter this command:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p Passw0rd
```

But receive this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How to find if my password is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a MySQL account, the hostname is important. Many people will use something like `'zabbix'@'%'`, but this should be used only if the MySQL database is on a different physical server from the web application. For a local connection, you'll want to use `'zabbix'@'localhost'`. Of course, there's no reason why you cannot use both.

Here's how:

1. Connect to MySQL Server as an administrator (or as `root`). If doing this from Terminal, you can type:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Once connected to MySQL, create the user account:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'zabbix'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `superSecretPassword!123` with a proper password. You can reuse the same password as was used for 'zabbix'@'%' if you would like.</sup>
3. Ensure the new account has all the permissions necessary to work with the necessary database(s):

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON `zabbix`.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost';
   ```
4. Disconnect from MySQL:

   ```
   exit
   ```

That's all there is to it

Comment: Hi Matigo,I Managed to do it and now able to log in but now Zabbix is showing as Zabbix server is running No localhost:10051  please help

Comment: This new issue is completely different from the database problem, so you will want to create a new question to deal with the port problem. Be sure to include your Apache (or nginx) configuration files, as they will be important to provide a solution.